# How to load and index files with parquet format to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, parquet

I have a very large parquet file which I need to import it to elasticsearch. I searched on the net but could not find useful result. I wonder if  latest version of elasticsearch would support such format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the author of [Moshe/elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/Moshe/elasticsearch_loader)
I wrote ESL for this exact problem.
You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader[parquet]
```

And then you will be able to load parquet files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader --index incidents --type incident parquet file1.parquet file2.parquet
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use [`ConvertUtils`](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-compatibility/blob/master/parquet-compat/src/test/java/parquet/compat/test/ConvertUtils.java) and call the [`convertParquetToCSV()`](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-compatibility/blob/master/parquet-compat/src/test/java/parquet/compat/test/ConvertUtils.java#L111) method.

Then when your CSV file has been generated, you can simply consume it by using  Logstash with

- a [`file` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html),
- a [`csv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) and
- an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

Sample configuration:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/your/parquet/as/csv/file"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["col1", "col2"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good idea, i wonder if there is any way to directly do that without data conversion cost

Comment: @arefehTam and how would you convert a binary columnar parquet data without incurring any conversion cost into a document store like elasticsearch? They are completely different representations...